# CSRF error when posting file on GAE using Django-nonrel

Tags: django, google-app-engine, caching, django-nonrel

I'm having a problem when I try to post a file.

It works fine when I'm on dev server,

but on GAE, I can only post text only, never a file.

Below is the form I am using:

```
<form id="file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" action="{{ upload_url }}">
{% for field in upload_form %}
    <div class="field">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
            <div class="input">
                {{ field }} {{ field.help_text }}
            </div>
            {% if field.errors %}
                <ul class="errors">
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error|escape }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

I believe that I have included appropriate middlewares

```
# Media middleware has to come first
'mediagenerator.middleware.MediaMiddleware',
# This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',# the "update" middleware must be first
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', # Session middleware needs to come before Auth middleware, because authentication is handled with sessions.
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.csrf.middleware.CsrfViewMiddleware',# It should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',# the "fetch" middleware must be last
'google.appengine.ext.appstats.recording.AppStatsDjangoMiddleware',
```

I see django is adding a hidden input called "csrfmiddlewaretoken" with some csrf token value on dev server and on GAE as well.

However, whenever I attempt to upload a file it gives me the csrf error message.

I suspect that caching is causing this problem since it started soon after I included caching middlewares.

For now I'm trying to solve this problem by reordering my middlewares but no luck so far.

Did anyone faced my problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Include the tag {% csrf_token %} somewhere in your form.

Comment: That doesn't apply in this case.

CsrfResponseMiddleware

adds csrf token automatically